# two field in which one is degree Foreign key and study as null

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns. SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE tdegree
(
    degree varchar(25)  NOT NULL primary key
)

CREATE TABLE tstudy
(
    study varchar(25)  NOT NULL unique,
    degree varchar(25)  NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tdegree (degree)
)
```

as shown in below figure I want to add record

> master it
>
> mphil it

but not

> master it
>
> master it

If I apply unique constraints on study field then it does not allowed me to add

> master it
>
> mphil it

Which constraints i have to apply?

[image]

Comment: image linked with this text(which constraints i have to apply) plz click it thanks in advance and sory for disturbance to understand my words and method of asing question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the combination of `study` and `degree` to be unique, but values can be repeated in individual columns e.g. Row 1 is Master + IT and Row 2 is MPhil + IT, so that both rows are unique but `study` column has duplicate value IT. In that case, you need to add a unique constraint on both columns together like so:

```
alter table tstudy add constraint cunique unique(study,degree)
```

Note that you also need to change the definition of your `tstudy` table and remove the unique constraint on `study` column, otherwise you will get a unique constraint violation error, even after adding the above constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE tstudy
(
 study varchar(25)  NOT NULL,
 degree varchar(25)  NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tdegree (degree)
)
```